# При получении данных из MS SQL sqlsrv данные "varchar" длиннее 16-17 символов не отдаются

Tags: php, sql

```
/* строка запроса */
$query = "SELECT OwnerName FROM pMark";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
if( $stmt === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
/* заполнение массива */    
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    $result[] = $row; 
}
/* вывод */
echo '<pre>';
   print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

OwnerName - это колонка с фамилиями Varchar. При заполнении массива всегда останавливается на самой длинной фамилии (опытным путем вычислил, что более 16 символов). Насколько я понял в sqlsrv_query нужно указать параметры "$params", но я не смог разобраться с синтаксисом и не нашел примера.

Comment: Вообще не должно. А вы при подключении кодировку устанавливаете? Если нет, то в sqlsrv_connect добавьте параметр `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"`

Comment: Это помогло! То что я получил половину данных и они были верными ввело меня в заблуждение, что кодировку указывать не надо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При работе с MSSQL желательно в параметрах подключения к БД указывать одним из параметров кодировку данных:

```
"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
```